# scalikejdbc pagination

Tags: sql, scala, pagination, scalikejdbc

I just wondering how can I apply offset and limit query parameters in case of use `one.toManies` API with several left joins?

My sample DSL is:

```
withSQL {
        select.from(CustomerTable as cust)
          .leftJoin(SocialNetworkTable as sn).on(cust.id, sn.customerId)
          .leftJoin(MailingTable as ml).on(cust.id, ml.customerId)
}.one(CustomerTable(cust)).toManies(...)
```

So I want to paginate over parent `CustomerTable`.

Do you have any best practices to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Skinny ORM's pagination feature would be better (or implementing your own one...).

http://skinny-framework.org/documentation/orm.html